# How to make Vim GUI tab menu to look like Console tab menu

Tags: vim, vi

When more than one file is opened in vim in console(terminal) with tabnew  we will get a tabbed interface for each file. My question is can we get the same look and feel for gvim(GUI) rather than having real GUI tabbed interface for each file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
:set guioptions-=e
```

in the command-line or

```
set guioptions-=e
```

in your `~/.vimrc`.

See `:help guioptions` for more options.